# How to get parent's DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

iv'e got a **ListBox** which is bound to a list of **Player**  , the listbox's parent 
as a datacontext with a property of Players .

```
   <ListBox>
       <ListBox.Items>
          <Binding Path="Players"></Binding>
       </ListBox.Items>
       <DataTemplate>
          <ListBoxItem>                                        
              <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
              <Button ToolTip="Invite To Play" x:Name="btn_InviteToPlay" Click="btn_InviteToPlay_Click>                                         
          </ListBoxItem>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <ListBox>
```

on the buttons click event i need to get the value of **Player** that is bound to this 
listboxitem (the one containing the button which was clicked )

```
  private void btn_InviteToPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      Button btn = (Button)sender;
      // how to retrieve player bound to current listboxitem ?   
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btn.DataContext` should already contain the `Player` as the `DataContext` is inherited by controls in the `ListBoxItem`.

Answer (score 1):

If you were binding to ListBox.ItemsSource instead of ListBox.Items then in addition to H.B.'s solution you could:

1) name the list box (say x:Name="theListBox") and retrieve the selected player in your code behind

```
var player = (Player)theListBox.SelectedValue;
```

2) add a SelectedPlayer property to your view model and bind that to your list box

```
<ListBox SelectedValue={Binding SelectedPlayer} />
```