# Change GridView's SelectedItem while selecting datatemplate control in phone application

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

The GridView in MainPage.xaml binds to an ObservableCollection of Employee. And the Employee class has got Amount(double) property that I want to edit through a TextBox. And finally when the text is entered I want to do some operation on the remaining Employee objects. I am able to get at the edited object via the INotifyPropetyChanged/PropertyChanged. But I think I cannot perform the operation here since it will trigger a cyclic PropertyChange for each of the object's update that I may perform on the other objects? Ideally, I should rely on the TextChanged event of the TextBox to do this.

The problem that I face is I am not able to get the edited object selected against the GridView's SelectedItem(SelectedEmployee). I can manage to get it selected only if I click/tap it outside the TextBox and within the row but not when I click directly in the TextBox. I wonder there is a way to trigger/update the GridView's SelectedItem when the TextBox is directly tapped?

Below my MainPage.xaml

```
<storeApps:VisualStateAwarePage
x:Class="SimpleCurrency.Views.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SimpleCurrency.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:storeApps="using:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps"
xmlns:mvvm="using:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm"    
mc:Ignorable="d"
mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">


<GridView Margin="12,20,12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" x:Name="grdEmployees"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeGridTemplate}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay}">        
</GridView>
```

And the DataTemplate EmployeeTemplate

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EmployeeGridTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Departments, ElementName=grdEmployees, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValuePath="Code"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Amount, Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="Number">
            <!--TODO: Need to get at text chagned event-->
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
                    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ConvertCommand, ElementName=grdConversions}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Open to any suggestion/workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tap event of the TextBox is preventing the GridView from noticing the tap event because it is "below" the TextBox tap area. 
You should be able to determine which employee is bound to your TextBox (Databinding Context) and use this information to programmatically set the selected item of your GridView to the Employee Instance.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me to some examples if you know or anywhere that I could take a look at?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364465/how-to-get-parents-datacontext where the button is clicked instead of your TextBox but the Datacontext is determined based on the parent control.

Comment: Yes, I have found some examples without code behind